# Magento frontend (session) cookie

Tags: magento

i have some strange behaviour in IE on my magento shop with loosing the frontend (session) cookie. does anybody has a clue, where in the magento code the frontend cookie gets set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Afaik, the `'frontend'` cookie gets set right before the current action is being dispatched.

Have a look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()`.

#### Session start

Looking into `preDispatch()`, find the line which starts the session:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $namespace))->start();
```

Which usually (if not overridden) finally maps to

```
 Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start()
```

This is the place where all the standard session stuff gets initialized, *including* cookie settings by using [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

#### Revalidation

Be aware though, that once the cookie already exists, first cookie mangling may already happen while the core session gets instantiated, i.e. before `start()` is called. That's because the constructor calls `revalidateCookie()` while instantiating the core session. See:

```
 Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::init()
```